# What is the difference between systemctl start [service] and systemctl start [service].service?

Tags: command-line, systemd

With the commands `systemctl start apache2` and `systemctl start apache2.service`, is there any difference between them?

What does the `.service` mean? Does it do anything that `systemctl start apache2` does not?

Or is `apache2` just the shortened version of `apache2.service`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First link with Google `systemctl start why .service` has the answer. Here the [copypasta](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) :)

---

> In systemd, the target of most actions are “units”, which are resources that systemd knows how to manage. Units are categorized by the type of resource they represent and they are defined with files known as unit files. The type of each unit can be inferred from the suffix on the end of the file.

> For service management tasks, the target unit will be service units, which have unit files with a suffix of .service. However, **for most service management commands, you can actually leave off the .service suffix**, as **systemd is smart enough** to know that you probably want to operate on a service when using service management commands.

Answer (score 0):

No difference between them.

`.service` is the unit file containing all information necessary to control the service (start, restart, stop, logging etc.)

Yes, `apache2` is the shorter version of `apache2.service` for the question's context.